# How to use Jquery to remove an overflowing element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overflow

Pretty simple problem, but I can't find a solution. [This plugin](http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/removeoverflow.php) claims to do it, but I can't get it to work on my site at all, not as a called script, not inline, nothing. So, I have two columns of divs, the ones on one side larger than the other. I have set it up so the second column container will match the height of the first (which is determined elsewhere and thus varies) and set it to overflow:hidden, but what I want to do do is to remove the overflowing divs entirely so it always ends on the last complete div. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bw2v39ru/2/

This is the JS to equalize the heights `$('.row2').css('height', $('.row1').height()+'px');`

In that example, only two of he block2 spans should be visible and the overflowing ones removed completely instead of leaving half a block.

Comment: For me, the plugin is working well, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/bw2v39ru/4/

Comment: Judging from your title, get the offsetHeight of the element and then the scrollHeight and see if scrollHeight is larger than offsetHeight, if so, then remove the element.

Comment: @Buzinas I added it in just like you have it and it does seem to be working now, at least no errors. Doh! Thank you.

Comment: @www139 This could be a fall back too. Thanks!

Comment: @Epleroma if you want the code; I can make a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: @www139 Please, I would appreciate it. I actually did another test right now and its not working again, despite not giving any errors.

Comment: Let me finish math first ;) still doing school. Like another 30 min and I should be ready to write a jsfiddle for you. If you need an answer sooner than that, somebody else can create the jsfiddle based from my suggestion.

Comment: Ok, starting work on the jsfiddle ;)

Comment: Thank you! Seems like the other solutions aren't working either

Answer (score 3):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/bw2v39ru/9/

Besides the code below - you will have to e.g. insert a `<br style="clear:both;" />` in the parent DIV since the children has `float: left`

```js
$('.row2').css('height', $('.row1').height());

var maxHeight = $("#main").outerHeight();
$("#main span").each(function() {
    var elm = $(this);
    if (elm.offset().top + elm.height() > maxHeight)
        elm.remove();
});
```

Comment: Good quick way, well done! In my example during calculation i additionally have a function for calculating element heights to reuse on other situations.

Comment: @andersmad Ok, so I tried this and it does not seem to be working, but I also realized I did not explain the situation well enough. On my actual site, there is no #main box and I'm basing the length of the second row purely on the height of the first. I changed it in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bw2v39ru/8/  and your method still works, but its not working on my site. Here is the actual page I'm testing it on: http://www.luxurytradingclub.com/ltc_store_details.php?id=210&type=9

Comment: @andersmad the code:   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ltc_list_5').css('height', $('#list_1').height()+'px');
        });
      
     
        var maxHeight = $("#list_1").outerHeight();
       $(".ltc_list_5").each(function() {
      var elm = $(this);
      if (elm.offset().top + elm.height() > maxHeight)
        elm.remove();
});
      
    </script>

Comment: I did end up getting this to work, but i'm running into an issue with one of the larger blocks getting deleted despite it having exactly enough room to fit. How can I add an extra 5px to one of the variables correctly here to fix the calculation?

Comment: @Epleroma can't see how that could happen since padding, margin and border seems to work ok - but you could just give the outer height a few more pixel: `$('.row2').css('height', $('.row1').height() + 5);` or check out `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: @AndersMad thanks, but that did not work, it simply added padding to the bottom but the last block that could fit gets taken out. Here is the link to the page, you can see the gap in the lower right corner where a third colored box should fit, but it gets removed. http://www.luxurytradingclub.com/ltc_store_details.php?id=205&type=4

Comment: @Epleroma try with the update fiddle (note the new link) or change it to `maxHeight + 5` - else try make a repro fiddle to find the culprit.

Comment: @AndersMad thank you, those options did not work either, so I'll try to reproduce it in the fiddle, but that may take some time as I have no idea what is causing this...

Comment: It finally worked! Only had to change it to `maxHeight + 230`

Answer (score 2):

as promised, here is my answer. Custom build jsfiddle from pure JavaScript.
https://jsfiddle.net/www139/vjgnsrpg/

Here is a code snippit for you. It assumes that all of your block2 elements have a fixed height. Also I changed the .row1 and .row2 classes to ids to make the solution easier to create. Feel free to change it back but remember to use `document.getElementsByClassName('class')[i]` instead.

```js
//make sure you execute this script onload inside a jquery document ready or window.onload

//get the rendered height of both rows
//enter margin for blocks here
//this also assumes that the height of your block1 and block2 elements are fixed
var margin = 5;
var rowOneHeight = document.getElementById('row1').offsetHeight;
//get height of block2 element including vertical margin (multiplied twice)
var blockTwoHeight = document.getElementById('row2').getElementsByClassName('block2')[0].offsetHeight + 2 * margin;
var howManyBlocksCanFit = Math.floor(rowOneHeight / blockTwoHeight);
var numberOfBlocks = document.getElementById('row2').getElementsByClassName('block2').length;
for (var i = 0; i != numberOfBlocks - howManyBlocksCanFit; i++) {
  document.getElementById('row2').removeChild(document.getElementById('row2').lastElementChild);
}
```

```css
#main {
  width: 240px;
}
#row1 {
  float: left;
}
#row2 {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.block2 {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="row1">
    <span class="block1"></span>
    <span class="block1"></span>
    <span class="block1"></span>
    <span class="block1"></span>
    <span class="block1"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="row2">
    <span class="block2"></span>
    <span class="block2"></span>
    <span class="block2"></span>
    <span class="block2"></span>
    <span class="block2"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you, please tell me if there was something I didn't understand in your question to improve my answer.

Comment: Wonderful; hope it helps ;)

Comment: How did it work out? I can always redo it for you or help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I programmed it for you, this works after your existing JS code line:

```
var row2 = $('div.row2'),
    block2elements = row2.children('span.block2');

// Function to use also for other situations
function calculateElementsHeight(elements) {
    var height = 0;
    $.each(elements, function(i, elementRaw ){ 
        height += $(elementRaw).height();
    })
    return height;
}

for(var i = 0; block2elements.length > i; i++) {
    block2elements = row2.children('span.block2'); // Get new state of the block2 elements
     if(row2.height() < calculateElementsHeight(block2elements)) {
         block2elements.last().remove();
     }
}
```